# Comparing wavelets with unequal lengths

Tags: classification, python, wavelet

I have a bunch of time varying data stored as arrays with 0 and 1 in them, like this:

`[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, ...]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, ...]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, ...]`

I want to compare these using DWT and use that in a classifier. The problem is that they are of unequal lengths - the smallest being 32 and the biggest 800, so that's quite a big difference. I made a test with Haar transforms on arrays that I completely made up (with equal lengths), and that worked with 100% accuracy, so I really like the power of these transforms!

Is there any way to compare these wavelets to each other? Let's say I want them of length 8 or 16. How would I do that? I'm using the PyWavelets package in Python.

Comment: Hello @Ferdi I'm having the same problem as you. Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: It was not my problem. I just did a minor formatting edit and I have no solution for this problem.